# Close questions as "belongs on serverfault" without automatically migrating

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderation

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104958/apache-2-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-to-php-5-3-closed) on SO as "belongs on serverfault".  The user had already taken the suggestion to [ask the question in the correct forum](https://serverfault.com/questions/38434/apache-2-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-to-php-5-3), so unfortunately when I closed it, the automatic migration created [a duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/38441/apache-2-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-to-php-5-3).  It would be nice if this migration wasn't automatic, particularly for moderators who can migrate questions manually.

I think the easiest solution in these rare cases where the question is already asked on SF is to simply close the question as "no longer relevant" to avoid the duplicate on SF, but I wanted to bring this to people's attention since it's a very quick and easy mistake to make.

Comment: Also, I flagged the duplicate for the SF moderators and they cleaned it up already, so thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be for the question asker to migrate it himself.

There might be the possibility for this to be abused, but not anymore than everything else.