# Identify cross-posting on sister sites

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I've noticed a few questions lately where OP will post on SO, then be told in a comment that it's better suited to a sister site. On the odd occasion, OP will then cross-post on said sister site but not make any note of this on the original question. I can find examples if necessary.

It shouldn't be difficult to identify cross-posting. The question is often identical, and even if not it is posted by the same user in quick succession.

How about posting a link in the questions to direct readers to the other cross-posts?

Comment: I think it's [those comments that are evil](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/belongs-on-comments).