# What kind of comment is not eligible for voting or flagging

Tags: support, comments, comment-voting

ON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556145/setting-up-a-network-e-mail-server
I saw a comment

Server setup -> not programming -> belongs on Serverfault.com – marc_s 27 secs ago

and tried to upvote the comment. I got the message

This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging.

What kind of comment is it?

Comment: As an aside: I don't like [such "belongs on" comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/belongs-on-comments), *at all*... But they cannot be flagged either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question is migrated, it is both [closed and locked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4556145/revisions).

It is the *latter* state that restricts activity. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) for a description of what a locked post is, and what activities are allowed/disallowed on them.

For comparison, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135044) is a closed question with comments, which can be voted on.