# People who comment "flagged"

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I just want to clarify the procedure on people leaving a comment on a question that says like "bad question... flagged" or "-1 flagged" or other questions of that kin, rather then constructive criticism on the actual post or silently flagging said post.

I find it non-constructive, rude and most of all, off-topic to write such a comment, so I flag these.

But I have seen plenty of these comments instead being upvoted, which makes me wonder what the official standpoint on this is.

Comment: That's just pointless noise. Flag it. (And don't yell "Flagged!").

Comment: @Bart Can I yell "YOU'RE IT!" or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting a comment about flagging a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193585/posting-a-comment-about-flagging-a-post)

Comment: No @jonsca. At most "punch buggy no punch back", when the post is about a bug.

Comment: I've actually seen this behavior less on SO than I have elsewhere

Comment: @ZachSmith I don't necessarily think that is a duplicate.  That post is talking about people who tell users when a question belongs on a different site.  This one is more about flagging comments about general flagging (i.e. "this post sucks, I have flagged it").  I think the handling of those is slightly different.

Comment: You can flag those comments as "too chatty."  That comment flag reason is for short and pointless comments, so I think "-1 flagged" fits perfectly.  Also, several SO mods check that flag category each day, so they should be cleaned up fairly quickly.

Comment: @Bart, jonsca: ***FLAGGED***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upvoting non-constructive, off-topic, and/or rude comments happens all the time because people on the internet can just be rude.  And since comment upvoting is 100% anonymous (except to the dev team), the users can be rude and not be called out by anyone.

So don't let the number of upvotes on a comment deter you.  If you feel a particular comment doesn't belong, then flag away.  The worst that will happen is a mod will decline your flag (which will only happen if they find the comment acceptable, constructive, and on-topic).

Comment: Do those flags still go to moderators? Most of them will end up being evaluated by the community if I'm not mistaken ...

Comment: @Bart for comment flags, I thought they all go to the 10K queue, so a moderator of some sort (10K or diamond) will handle them.  Unless of course multiple users flag it for the same and it is addressed automatically.

Comment: Ah, you count users as moderators. Okay.

Comment: @Bart If enough user flags come out the item will be auto-deleted.  If there aren't enough flags for that to happen, then a mod will get to it and cast a binding vote.  Since comments often aren't flagged enough for community action, the result is most comment flags are handled by a mod.

Comment: Comment flags never seem to be taken as seriously. Always bothered me that a "Not Constructive" flag of mine was declined on a comment "By hiring a developer, probably." on a post asking how to programmatically download .zip/.rar files from a site like Mediafire.

Comment: Comment flags are only seen by diamond mods. If enough people flag a comment it will go away on its own, but otherwise only we can see and handle them directly.

Comment: @Zach Smith: Yeah, about that...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn really?  I thought they flags other than "Other" go into the 10K queue.  That's good to know.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn What about it?